# iOS - Error : unrecognized selector sent to instance in PrepareForSegue:

Tags: ios, xcode

I wanna to pass data between controller, but I am getting this error, and I am blocked here :s

### Error :

```
 [UITabBarController setUID:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

### Code :

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
NSString *test = (NSString *)sender;  
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueno"]) {
    FirstViewController *VC = (FirstViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
    VC.uID = test;
    NSLog(@"%@",VC.uID);
}}
```

### Here is storyboaard

[image]

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast destinationViewController. 
FirstViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
should be enough (and use lower case as a convention).
Are you sure it is the vc.uID = test; that causes the error?

Comment: what is the type of the property uID?

Comment: See here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781674/passing-variables-between-view-controllers-using-segue/21812899#21812899

Comment: Check this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781674/passing-variables-between-view-controllers-using-segue/21812899#21812899

Answer (score 2):

Check what is actual type of VC during runtime. Looks like you cast to wrong type.

To check real type during runtime set breakpoint on line `VC.uID = test;`. In debug window you should have something like:

```
VC = (RealClass *) 0x312321312
```

Real class is not what you expected.

The most possible reason, that `VC` is `UITabBarController`. So you have to replace

```
FirstViewController *VC = (FirstViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
```

with

```
UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)[segue destinationViewController];
// replace 1 with real index of your FirstVC
FirstViewController *VC = [[tabBarController viewControllers] objectAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: Edited ! Can you more explain ?

Comment: @user3405229 post your storyboard, please

Comment: @user3405229 between what VC are you making segue?

Comment: LoginViewController and FirstViewController

Comment: @user3405229 your storyboard is cropped on provided image. I can't see FirstViewController

Comment: You are not segueing from Login to First, are you? In your storyboard, though cropped and difficult to read, it seems you are segueing to tabbarcontroller...

Comment: No, I am segueing from Login to First

Comment: @NikitaTook how do you get the index of your VC?

Answer (score 1):

segue destination is UITabBarController. so you need to check viewcontrollers list. then based on that u can look for uID.

```
    - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    {
        NSString *test = (NSString *)sender;

        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueno"]) {

            FirstViewController *firstVC ;

            UITabBarController *destinat = [segue destinationViewController];

            if ([destinat isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]]) {


                for (id listOfViewControllers in [destinat viewControllers]) {

                    if ([listOfViewControllers isKindOfClass:[FirstViewController class]]) {

                        firstVC = listOfViewControllers;

                        break;
                    }

                }

            }

            firstVC.uID = test;
            NSLog(@"%@",firstVC.uID);
        }}
```

Comment: I am getting : `(null)`

Comment: Again, getting `(null)` :s

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I pass managedObjectContext between segues

In your class where you will pass the data use prepareForSegue call. (The assumption is this class has a variable called **_managedObjectContext** which can be passed along to the segue class)

Class to Segue From:

.h file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

.m file:

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext
```

The call to @synthesize will make the following:

- a local variable called **_managedObjectContext**
- a method to **getManagedObjectContext**
- a method to **setManagedObjectContext**

Additionally add the following method to your class

```
// Pass on managedObjectContext
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

// If the destination VC is able to take the setManagedObjectContext method the current objectContext will be passed along.
if ([segue.destinationViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setManagedObjectContext:)]) {
    [segue.destinationViewController performSelector:@selector(setManagedObjectContext:)
                                          withObject:_managedObjectContext];
} else {

    NSLog(@"Segue to controller [%@] that does not support passing managedObjectContext", [segue destinationViewController]);
 }
}
```

Then in my "class" to receive the data I do:
in the .h file i have

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
```

and in the .m file i have:

```
@synthesize managedObjectContext;
```

What this does (with syntehsiation) is make a setManagedObjectContext and getManagedObjectContext call.  Upon being about to segue I check to make sure the destinationController will "respond to" this method, if so the data gets set.

clear?